# How to change Echo output font size including EchoLabel within an entire Notebook?

Tags: notebooks, customization, fonts, debugging, user-interface

I am creating a notebook template. I have Input and Output font size set at 10 but the Echo font size is 12. How do I change Echo to font size of 10? I cannot find a setting for this in Option Inspector.

Comment: You can edit the stylesheet and set the style of `"Echo"` to whatever you want.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you that worked. i did look for it in `Edit  -> Stylesheet` then looking under `Choose a style` and could not find it.  But it did motivate me to enter `Echo` in the search box which did find it.

Comment: Yeah, there are hundreds of styles, not all on the menu.